# webpage access blocked from command line but not browser

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to set up a cron job to run this command every day:

```
wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The website example.com is located on the same server I'm running the cron job from. But I keep getting an error 403 in my logs:

```
"GET /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron HTTP/1.1" 403 428 "-" "Wget/1.17.1 (linux-gnu)"
```

When I try to access the same url from my browser it works though:

```
"GET /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron HTTP/1.1" 200 304 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

So I guess there is something blocking requests from my own server in my apache2.conf (or .htaccess file), but I have no idea what to look for. Any idea what line could be responsible of this?

Comment: **a)** you shouldn't redirect and discard error messages (with `>/dev/null 2>&1`) when you have issues with a  particular job... **b)** rather than a web request simply let cron run the script directly (which potentially also allows you to increase security by moving it outside your webroot) with something similar to:  `/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/wp-cron.php` **c)** I would expect a message in the server's error log in addition to the GET requests you see explaining why the request is blocked

Comment: @HBruijn a/ there is no output for wget whether or not I add `>dev/null 2>&1` b/ with `usr/bin/php` nothing seems to happen (I see nothing in my apache logs) and if I add `?doing_wp_cron` to the wp-cron.php path I get `could not open input file` c/ I see no additional message in the server's error log

Comment: *Any idea what line could be responsible of this?* Line 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a rewrite condition in my .htaccess blocking some user agents, I guess including empty user agents. Adding `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"` did the trick:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" http://example.com/wp-cron.php
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden